# How do I convert a x86 RPM to a x86 DEB within a x64 system?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, deb, rpm, alien

In my case the software I am trying to convert is the Lacie lightscribe labeler.

1.- I renamed the RPM

```
mv LaCie\ LightScribe\ Labeler\ 1.0\ Linux.rpm lacie-lightscribe-labeler-1.0.rpm
```

2.- Convert the package with **alien**

```
sudo alien lacie-lightscribe-labeler-1.0.rpm
```

Error:

```
lacie-lightscribe-labeler-1.0.rpm is for architecture i386 ; the package cannot be built on this system
```

I know that:

- I could do this in a x86 system and then copy it from there.
- Use the simple labeler

I'm curious about how to do this conversion in general.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.matt-helps.com/using-alien-to-convert-rpm-packages-to-lpia-deb) can help you. Not sure since I am not familiar with `alien`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The process is quite easy, in short you need to modify the control file and that's it.

```
sudo alien -g package-name.rpm
cd package-dir/
sudo vi debian/control
```

Now change the architecture (`i386` in my case) to be the one you need. For example,
I added the `amd64` architecture and this is how the line ended up:

```
Architecture: i386, amd64
```

Last step:

```
sudo debian/rules binary
```

This will produce the `.deb` file.

---

### References:

- [Using Alien to convert .rpm packages to lpia .deb](https://www.matt-helps.com/post/using-alien-to-convert-rpm-packages-to-lpia-deb/)

Comment: +1 Can one do that on a 32 bit machine too? Or you need only to be on 64 bit to achieve that.

Answer (score 10):

I made it work with just this command:

```
fakeroot alien --target=amd64 package.i586.rpm
```

Comment: fakeroot in action, it was meant for this kind of thing

Comment: What version of `alien` is that? I have 8.86 on Ubuntu 12.04.5, and `target` is an unknown option.  (Time to upgrade Ubuntu!)

Answer (score 1):

This should be an easy work-around as well, as found on https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-32bit-rpm-to-deb-64bit/ - use TGZ as an intermediate stage:

```
sudo alien --scripts --to-tgz <package.rpm>

sudo alien --scripts --to-deb <package.tgz>
```

The `--to-deb` is a default, used here only to be explicit about the conversions.

Then, install with `dpkg` as usual (when using a raw .deb from Alien).