# convert 32bit rpm to deb on 64bit linux

Tags: package-management, software-installation, deb, convert, rpm

I downloaded backburner (renderfarm manager) from [here](https://apps.autodesk.com/MAYA/en/Detail/Index?id=appstore.exchange.autodesk.com%3Aautodeskbackburner_windows64%3Aen) .
I tried to convert it with `sudo alien -cv backburner.rpm` but terminal prints out

*backburner.rpm is for architecture i386 ; the package cannot be built on this system*

Regarding this [How do I convert a x86 RPM to a x86 DEB within a x64 system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322624/how-do-i-convert-a-x86-rpm-to-a-x86-deb-within-a-x64-system) i did

```
sudo alien -g backburner.rpm
cd backburner-dir/
sudo nano debian/control  (change i386 to amd64 )
sudo debian/rules binary
```

and I get following output

```
dh_testdir
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
dh_installdirs
dh_installdocs
dh_installchangelogs
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name debian -print0 | \
        xargs -0 -r -i cp -a {} debian/backburner.sw.base
dh_compress
dh_makeshlibs
dh_installdeb
dh_shlibdeps
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: debian/backburner.sw.base/usr/discreet/backburner/cmdjob contains an unresolvable reference to symbol uuid_generate: it's probably a plugin
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: 2 other similar warnings have been skipped (use -v to see them all)
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: debian/backburner.sw.base/usr/discreet/backburner/backburnerManager contains an unresolvable reference to symbol uuid_parse: it's probably a plugin
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: 2 other similar warnings have been skipped (use -v to see them all)
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: package could avoid a useless dependency if debian/backburner.sw.base/usr/discreet/backburner/cmdjob debian/backburner.sw.base/usr/discreet/backburner/backburnerServer debian/backburner.sw.base/usr/discreet/lib32/backburner/2015.0/libDLnrapi.so debian/backburner.sw.base/usr/discreet/backburner/backburnerManager were not linked against libuuid.so.1 (they use none of the library's symbols)
dh_gencontrol
dh_md5sums
dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: building package `backburner.sw.base' in `../backburner.sw.base_2015.0.1-1689_amd64.deb'.
```

**Could you guys explain and help me with those warnings ??**

I already tried adding libuuid.so.1 (with and without comma )inside debian/control Depends so it looked like

Depends: ${shlibs:Depends} , libuuid.so.1

as [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) suggested i did

```
namei -lx ../backburner.sw.base_2015.0.1-1689_amd64.deb
```

output

```
f: backburner.sw.base_2015.0.1-1689_amd64.deb
-rwxrwxr-x render render backburner.sw.base_2015.0.1-1689_amd64.deb
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's saying that you shouldn't link the software against `libuuid` since the binaries don't use anything from that library. The dependencies are already correct.

Comment: Thanks muru. So what 's right and possible solution to output .deb? I spent whole day for searching and testing without any luck .

Comment: the output says it created a deb file. Look in the parent directory, it should be there.

Comment: Yeah it's there but it's kind of broken? ( ln -l  - red colored )

Comment: what's the output of `namei -lx ../backburner.sw.base_2015.0.1-1689_amd64.deb`?

Comment: Right now I'm on virtualBox and i get f: backburner.sw.base_2015.0.1-1689_amd64.deb
-rwxrwxr-x render render backburner.sw.base_2015.0.1-1689_amd64.deb

Comment: That's unreadable. Please [edit] your post to add the output.

Comment: I think i found a  workaround you could extract the rpm file and install.http://www.nkoubi.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-install-autodesk-maya-2011-on-debian-ubuntu/

Comment: The file looks like a normal file, not a link. I don't see anything broken.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I did it with [rpm > tgz > deb](https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-32bit-rpm-to-deb-64bit/) . But i suppose that what [Mohit Rajan](https://askubuntu.com/users/511262/mohit-rajan) suggested could be helpful to. I think now that even alien -g packagename and manual installation - copying of files could work too.
Thanks for that.

Anyway would be cool to know how to avoid such warnings and how to deal with them. I just don't want to ignore it without further investigation

Answer (score 0):

You can use alien, but I don't suggest that. Alien can change RPM to DEB or DEB to RPM, but it can not make sure the package can be installed without any problem.